# document is undefined in document.getElementById, while writing unit test cases in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have written a code to disable a button using :

document.getElementBydId('btn').disabled = true;

This call is written inside componentWillUnmount life cycle event of react. Using this way because the button is coming from a common repo, which can't be accessed directly inside my component.

Now all the unit test cases for this component are failing and getting an error that 'document' is null. We are using jest for writing unit test cases.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: There's a typo, `getElementBydId`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of reasons why using DOM in React directly is discouraged.

`document.getElementById('btn').disabled` should be provided and mocked, wither with JSDOM or by stubbing variables explicitly.

JSDOM can be applied to global scope [directly](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html) or with [Jest configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) (it defaults to stubbing DOM with JSDOM).

It can also be stubbed with:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  global.document = {
    getElementById: jest.fn()
  }
});

afterEach(() => {
  delete global.document;
});

it('...', () => {
  document.getElementById.mockReturnValue({ disabled: true });
  ...
  expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalledWith('btn');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock getElementById in for your test case.

Then you can test if getElementById is called with correct params and disabled is being set to true (assuming it to be false before).

```
expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(document.getElementById.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe("btn");
expect(btnParams.disabled).toBeTruthy();
```

I have created a working test case for the same which can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/jznv48w32v

Please note that we are using beforeEach and afterAll in our test case.
beforeEach resets our mocked function after every test case.
afterAll is used to restore the value of the mocked function to original value.